# Making line thicker in Bayesian Network R

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I made a Bayesian Network in R using the `bnviewer` package. However I need the lines to be much thicker. I know they refer to the lines as edges, so in the documentation there is no option for `edge.size` or `edge.width`. I don't know if I am mission something, but it is annoying to print these networks to barely see the edge lines between the nodes. Here is an example of the script:

```
Title1 <- "Discrete Bayesian Network"
Subtitle1 <- "Interactions of tillage, cropping systems, nematodes and various parameters"
FigureTitle <- ""

viewer(res,
       bayesianNetwork.width = "100%",
       bayesianNetwork = 5,
       bayesianNetwork.height = "80vh",
       bayesianNetwork.layout = "layout_in_circle",
       bayesianNetwork.title=Title1,
       bayesianNetwork.subtitle = Subtitle1,
       bayesianNetwork.footer = FigureTitle
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I released an update of 'bnviewer' on my github that contains the inclusion of the `edges.width` parameter. I intend to release on CRAN soon.

To install bnviewer via git, follow the excerpt below:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("robson-fernandes/bnviewer")
```

Here is an example of R code for building a Bayesian network with the configuration of the `edges.width` parameter

```
library(bnlearn)
library(bnviewer)

bayesianNetwork = hc(gaussian.test)

viewer(bayesianNetwork, edges.width = 1)
```

Cheers

Robson Fernandes